# Interface that is also a Display Object

Tags: actionscript-3

I have some classes that implement an interface, but also extend the Sprite class:

```
package {
    public interface IState {
        function addMonster():void;
    }
}

package {
    public class Fuzzy extends Sprite implements IState {
        public function addMonster():void {

        }
    }
}

package {
    public class LizardSkin extends Sprite implements IState {
        public function addMonster():void {

        }
    }
}

// Document class 

package {
    public class Main extends MovieClip {
        private var state:IState;
        public function Main():void {
            state = new Fuzzy();

            addChild(state);
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to addChild(state) I keep getting an error message 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type IState to an unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject.

Now I know I've seen examples where a class extends MovieClip / Sprite and implements an interface...what can I do to make it so I can add "state" to the stage but also implement the methods I want??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple cast should do it most of the time:

```
addChild(state as DisplayObject);
```

The compiler raises that error otherwise because it doesn't assume `IState` is always implemented by something that is a `DisplayObject`, but if you can guarantee that condition you can always cast.

Comment: THANKS this helped a lot. I thought I was going to have to write a whole abstract class that implemented the interface.

Answer (score 2):

What I do in situations like this is use an IDisplayable interface, that looks like this:

```
public interface IDisplayable
{
   function get displayObject():DisplayObject;
}
```

and its implementation in a Sprite or MovieClip simply looks like this:

```
public function get displayObject():DisplayObject
{
     return this;
}
```

Your IState objects could then be added to the stage using `addChild(state.displayObject);`, when your IState interface extends IDisplayable.

Comment: I use this method as well. An additional benefit is you can have a class be an "Actor" for a DisplayObject, rather than forcing your own class to extend DisplayObject. Coded right, the "handler" won't notice a difference between the two situations.